# Can macOS flat file pkg installer throw error dialog?

Tags: macos, installation, pkgbuild

I want to throw error dialog (and fail the installation) if certain file exists on the system. Is it possible?
pkg = [flat file pkg](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Stuff/Ivanhoe/FLAT.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to customize the installer in various ways to get whatever functionality is needed generally. Typically in your scenario either a `Pre-Installation` script could be used or a `Package Installer Plugin`. The options would normally be defined in the installer package's `distribution.dist` which essentially functions as the schema it will follow.

See **[`productbuild`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/productbuild.1.html)** in the man pages:

> **--scripts scripts-path**
>   - The contents of scripts-path is added to the product archive for use by system.run() commands commands in the distribution.  This is valid only for product archives targeted to the OS X Installer application.
>
> **--plugins plugins-path**
>   - The contents of plugins-path is added to the product archive for use by the OS X Installer application's plugin mechanism.  It will normally contain a InstallerSections.plist file, and one or more plugin bundles.

↳ [About Distribution Definition Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/DistributionDefinitionRef/Chapters/Introduction.html) &  [productbuild](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/productbuild.1.html)

Comment: I already have script that returns non-zero exit code and installation fails. Problem is that user doesn't know what failed and I cannot throw custom text describing what failed.

Comment: @NulledPointer, I'd suggest then to create an installer plug-in; you can present any type of Cocoa interface, window (modal windows work well in that situation), etc. going that route. Apple used to have an example somewhere, although I'm not finding it. Since it seems you are using `Packages` there might be something in the documentation there as well.

Comment: @NulledPointer: I found an [archived Apple example](http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/samplecode/InstallerPluginSample/) ( yes it's old, although the same principles apply ).